# In UML, does an object's state machine define the object's lifecycle?

Tags: uml, state-machine

In UML, does an object's state machine define that object's lifecycle?

That is, do transitions from the [initial state](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/state-machine-diagrams.html#initial-pseudostate) to an ordinary state create the object, and transitions to the [final state](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/state-machine-diagrams.html#final-state) dispose of that object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally yes - at least that's probably the most common way of using them.

It's not mandated that way in [the UML spec](http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.3/Superstructure/PDF/); it allows a more general use of state machines.  For example, a Final State can be used to signify the end of a behaviour thread within a region if the state machine has >1 regions.  Or a state machine can be used to define a protocol instead of an object's lifecycle.

Some variants (profiles) of UML do enforce the behaviour you describe, for example [Executable UML](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=executable%20uml&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCkQFjAA&url=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_UML&ei=aIm5TqKPEMS0hAfn9N21Bw&usg=AFQjCNGZWUIgP1BBzbSp3fwo1Wg-eCWeRA&cad=rja).

I'd probably turn the question on its head and ask: would it be useful to you if the state machine did define the object's lifecycle?  If so then just use it that way.  If you need to formalise then you *could* define a profile.  But it's equally fine to just agree informally in your team.

hth.